# Dynamic CSS classes in React for image modals

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple photo gallery in React. When I click on the photo preview, I want a modal of the larger image to pop up.

I have this working so far. The modal element itself is originally set to a class with `display: none;`. My problem is that when I click on one photo, **every single modal pops up.**

How can I change the class name of one specific modal element so this does not happen?

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import images from './../data/images';
import './../css/Photos.css';

class Photos extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      images: images,
      visible: false,
      //invisibleClass: 'photo-modal-invisible',
      visibleClass: 'photo-modal-invisible'
    };
  }

/*
  Applies the appropriate class for the modal
  when the image is clicked. Class is handled
  in state.
 */

handleClick() {
  const isVisible = this.state.visible;

  if(isVisible === false) {
    this.setState({ visible: true, visibleClass: 'photo-modal-visible' });
  } else {
    this.setState({ visible: false, visibleClass: 'photo-modal-invisible' });
  }
}

  render() {

    var correctClass;

    return(
      <React.Fragment>
      <div className="photo-container">
        {
          this.state.images.map((image, index) =>
            <a onClick={ () => this.handleClick() }><img src={ image.imageSrc } key={ index } /></a>
          )
        }
      </div>
        {
          this.state.images.map(( image, index ) =>
          <div className={ this.state.visibleClass } key={ index }>
            <a href="#" onClick={ () => this.handleClick() }><span class="close">&times;</span></a>
            <img src={ image.imageSrc } />
          </div>
          )
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Photos;
```

```css
.photo-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.photo-container img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: 1s;
}

.photo-container img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}

.photo-modal-invisible {
  display: none;
}

.photo-modal-visible {
  position: fixed;
  /* stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* black with opacity */
}

.photo-modal-visible img {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: you can use the npm package called `classnames` and by the help of a boolean you could have the following css structure. 

```photo-modal (for all photos)
photo-modal is-visible
photo-modal is-invisible```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create another component for a single image and keep the visible state on a single image. So when you click on a single image, it's not affecting other image state.

Comment: Well shoot. That's a simple solution. I'm going to do that. Thanks! I'm still learning how to think in React.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the class name on all the images in the map function which is why all modal images area visible/hidden at the same time.

In the handleClick pass the index of the image and store that index in the state and use that to toggle the modal

Comment: I figured I had to do something like this. I'm not sure how storing the index in the state will help me assign the class to that specific image instead of all the ones being mapped.

Should I scrap map altogether? I figured I had to use it to generate the modals and then specify which one to show.